# UWP XAML Binding to another object is not working

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm trying to bind TextBlock Width to another object's Width.

It is not working, TextBlock Width stays as the Text length, and not as "BitsListView" Width.

An interesting thing is, when I edit the "Width" of TextBlock while debugging, the binding is working OK.

```
<StackPanel >
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
         <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind name}" Width="{Binding ElementName=BitsListView, Path=ActualWidth }"/>
     </StackPanel>

     <ListBox x:Name="BitsListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind BitsList, Mode=TwoWay}">
         <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
     </ListBox>                               
</StackPanel>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the following works? If it has solved your issue ,please consider accept it.

Comment: Hi thanks for solution I didn't test this because the Horizontal orientation is a must.

Comment: What is the real scenario in your production environment. In this scenario, it looks like when we set Horizontal the UI render system have no idea how it can render your textblock and listview in the Horizontal way which triggers your problem. Generally set it to vertical or disable Horizontal fix this. So the problem is what is your real request and can we think about a workaround for it.

Answer (score 0):

> UWP XAML Binding to another object is not working

The problem is that when set `TextBlock` root panel `Orientation` property as `Horizontal`, the width of content will be fixed. So, if you want to make `Binding` work, please remove `Orientation` property like the following.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock Name="TestBlock"  Text="Test input some"   Width="{Binding ElementName=BitsListView, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```